# How to get Taxonomy Menu working properly with Contextual Filters in Views?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I can't get taxonomy menu links working properly with contextual arguments in Views.

This is what I have done:

0) I create a menu called: **Catalog menu**

1) I create a Vocabulary called: **Catalog terms** and in the Taxonomy menu area I set Catalog menu for the Menu location *(I have Taxonomy menu module enabled which allow me to do this)*

2) I the Catalog vocabulary I added 2 terms: **Cars** and **Phones**

3) In admin/config/search/path/patterns I set **Pattern for all Catálogo taxonomy paths** to **catalog/[term:name]**

4) In admin/structure/block I enable the **Catalog menu** block to the **First sidebar**

So far so good. I have a menu in my first sidebar with the links: *cars* and *phones*.

5) I have a content type called **Products** with a field of the type **Term reference** called: field_catalog

6) Now I create a new view called: **Catalog view** where I need to show **Products** which has an specific term in the url. The path of this view is **catalog**

7) I added a RELATIONSHIP called: **Content (field_catalog)**

8) I added a CONTEXTUAL FILTERS called **Taxonomy term: Name** using the previous relationship

Now if I enter "cars" in the **Auto preview Preview with contextual filters:** area it works fine. It only shows **products** that has **cars** term.

So the Catalog Menus is fine and the view is fine.

But if I go to the url www.mysite.com/en/catalog/cars it takes me to the list of content that has the temr **cars**. Here I need to show the **Catalog view** passing **cars** as an argument and not that list.

Comment: Slightly off topic but I like how you started your ordered list with 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made one mistake that is easy to make. The alias created in the menu doesn't change the "true" url. So when you go to `catalog/cars` Drupal will perceive that as `taxonomy/term/[tid]`.

What you could do instead is to enable the default taxonomy term view that ships with Views (which uses `taxonomy/term/[tid]` as the path) and then set it up like you want.

See Screen shot:
[image: Views page]

Comment: I don't get it. Could you please explain how to do it? Where do I do these changes?

Comment: IN the list of available views you will find one with the taxonomy/term/% path.  that is the one you want to enable and create your view in.

Comment: Thanks what you said is useful, but I will try a different approach. I will create a view listing terms as a html list, so that I'll get the menu as a block.